# concatenación en php

Tags: php

Por favor me podrían indicar cuál es el problema, la concatenación está bien o eso creo.

```
<?php 
$n1=21;
$n2 =4;
$edad=$n1+$n2;
echo "Mi edad es". '<input type="text" value="'$edad'">';


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te falta el punto para concatenar la variable `$edad` como `value` del `input`:

```
$n1=21;
$n2 =4;
$edad=$n1+$n2;
echo "Mi edad es". '<input type="text" value="'.$edad.'">';
```

Para casos como estos es mejor poner todo en un solo bloque rodeado de comillas dobles, y escapar las comillas dobles interiores, por ejemplo:

```
echo "Mi edad es <input type=\"text\" value=\"$edad\">";
```

Así evitas tantas concatenaciones y combinaciones de `"` y `'` que se prestan muchas veces a confusión.